# Firestore latency-compensated snapshot return different between batch and transaction

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

My batch write is returning strange latency-compensated results for my snapshot listeners. The batch executes the write perfectly in the database and doesn't produce errors on the client but the snapshot listener (in the same app) that listens to one of these documents returns strange latency-compensated results. The batch:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
let batch = db.batch()
let timestamp = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

batch.updateData([
    "private.index.\(someId)": ["count": 0, "timestamp": timestamp]
], forDocument: db.collection("someCollection").document(uId))

batch.deleteDocument(db.collection("anotherCollection").document("\(uId)-\(someId)"))

batch.commit { (error) in

    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    }

}
```

If the snapshot listener ignores returns with `hasPendingWrites`, the data is fine because it's from the server (which is correct). But if the snapshot listener allows the latency-compensated data, I get this:

```
["count": 0, "t": <null>]]
```

While data from the server (and transactions) looks like this:

```
["count": 0, "t": <FIRTimestamp: seconds=1586033607 nanoseconds=198000000>]]
```

There is no reason the timestamp should ever be nil.

What's also strange is if I perform the same task in a transaction, there are no problems, even with latency-compensated data (it's correct).

```
db.runTransaction({ (trans, errorPointer) -> Any? in

    trans.updateData([
        "private.index.\(someId)": ["count": 0, "timestamp": timestamp]
    ], forDocument: db.collection("someCollection").document(uId))

    trans.deleteDocument(db.collection("anotherCollection").document("\(uId)-\(someId)"))

    return nil

}) { (_, error) in

    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    }

}
```

Are batch writes expected to sometimes not give consistent latency-compensated results since they don't work exactly like transactions do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently wrote a blog post about exactly this [behavior of server timestamps](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/the-secrets-of-firestores-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-revealed-29dd7a38a82b).  It doesn't have anything to do with batches - just plain old document writes will show the same behavior.    What you are seeing is actually the expected behavior.  But transactions behave differently because the local cache is not involved in transaction behavior, as it requires a full sync with the server to success (there are no pending writes to observe with transactions).

If you absolutely need a timestamp in the snapshot that hasn't been synchronized yet, you should **not** use [getData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getData()) with no arguments to get the data in the snapshot.  Instead, you should use [getData(serverTimestampBehavior)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#public-mapstring,-object-getdata-documentsnapshot.servertimestampbehavior-servertimestampbehavior).  The argument you pass:

> Configures the behavior for server timestamps that have not yet been set to their final value.

Your options for [ServerTimestampBehavior](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.ServerTimestampBehavior) let you choose if you want an estimate, none (nil, as you see now), or the previous value of the field.  Sounds like you want an estimate.

Comment: 1. I didn't know you had a blog and will now follow it. 2. I didn't think I'd be reading about something called leap smearing today but I just did. 3. Thanks as always, you're always so on top of your game.